# HIde Flex Video Player's controls

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I have skinned the controls of the video player through VidoePlayerSkin.
I need to play the video always in full screen and show / hide the controls on tap.

i can't access the VideoPlayerSkin class's  controls group element in action script. What is the solution for this?

*Edited* further query
This issue is solved but now if I want to use any controls the controls bar dissapears. It shouldn't when I click on an element inside the controls bar.? Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo code show/hide controls of VideoPlayer by click. Is that what you want?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="init()">

    <s:VideoPlayer id="video" source="rtmp://fmsexamples.adobe.com/vod/mp4:_cs4promo_1000.f4v"
                   width="100%" height="100%"
                   loop="true"
                   autoPlay="true" />
    <s:Button label="fullscreen" click="{stage.displayState = stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN ? StageDisplayState.NORMAL : StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN}"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void
            {
                video.videoDisplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onVideoClick);
            }
            private function onVideoClick(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                video.playerControls.visible = !video.playerControls.visible;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked for me. What worked was this vid_player.videoDisplay.parent.getChildAt(1).visible = true. Yes but i checked it in a new project and your solution works there , so some issue with my code.

Comment: I have experienced another issue on this . have edited the question